# How do I use Carnauba or Beeswax for Candy?

Tags: food-science, candy

I am trying to make gummies and I want to use either Carnauba wax or bees wax to make a coating, anyone got any idea WHAT Carnauba or bees wax to use and how to apply it? I know they use a tumbler but do I use Carnauba granules? Mix it with oil? What?

Answer (score 1):

For gummies in an industrial setting, these come pre-blended to simplify application and process.

In a kitchen or commercial setting, carnauba is usually applied as a finely ground powder because of the high melting temp.  For some applications like beeswax, cocoa butter, etc. a heated panner is common for the application of the hard shell.